# Retrieving Variable From A Javascript File

Tags: javascript, html

My question is how to share a variable between two different javascript files. I am creating a form that transfers the value to a different page, which alerts that variable. I have 2 html files (index.html and form.html) as well as 2 javascript files (form.js and index.js). So basicly I want to share the variable theNick from form.js to index.js to display it using alert(). If this is not possible, is there another way to do this?

form.html:

```
<input type="text" id="Nick" placeholder="Nickname">
<a id="btn" onclick="submit()" href="index.html.">Submit</a>
```

form.js:

```
function submit(){
     var theNick = document.getElementById("Nick").value; //retrieves theNick from your input
     ???

}
```

index.html:

```
<button onclick="callNick()">Click Me to view your Nickname.</button>
```

index.js:

```
function callNick(){
    ???????
    alert(theNick); //I want to get access to this variable from form.js
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sort of possible.

First of all you need to make certain that your HTML loads both JavaScript files. There isn't really a way for them to import each other, so the HTML must load both scripts.

Secondly, you need to modify your function `submit` to use a global variable. Global variables are initially defined outside the scope of a function. The function `callNick` is already looking for a global variable.

However, the `submit` function is defining its own, local variable because of the keyword `var` being used inside the function scope. Change it like so:

```
// Set global variable 
var theNick;

function submit(){
      // Use global variable 
      theNick = document.getElementById("Nick").value; //retrieves theNick from your input
      ???

}
```

See this article for further information.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: I have tried all of your steps. It seems like callNick is recognizing theNick, but it alerts 'undefined' instead of 'Bob'. It knows that it exists, but doesn't know the value of theNick. If I set theNick in the global scope to 'Bob', it will work, but it is't regognizing when it changes in submit. ideas?

Comment: You have to run your `submit()` function. And it must be run after your HTML containing the "Nick" element is loaded. It is common to place all JavaScript files as the last part in the html <body> tag.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [`var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) you are doing exactly the opposite. If you want to share something the easiest thing  would be to bind the variable to the [`window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window) like this: `window.theNick = ...` and use it like `alert(window.theNick)`.

Comment: I tried that just now but instead of saying 'Bob' as theNick it said 'undefined'. Any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: It depends on the time each function gets called

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare the variable outside of the function

```
var theNick; // you could omit this entirely since it will be declared in 
             // global scope implicitly when you try to assign it in the function
function submit(){
    theNick = document.getElementById("Nick").value; //retrieves theNick from your input
}
```

javascript does not care about which files declarations are made but in which scope.

By placing the variable in global scope you'll be able to access it everywhere.

Global variables are not the best coding strategy but this should help you with the concept

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your variable into the url, using the `?yourVar=` GET mark :

**form.js**

```
function submit(e){
     var theNick = document.getElementById("Nick").value; //retrieves theNick
     e.target.href+='?n='+theNick; // set the href of your anchor with your variable
}
```

**form.html**

```
<input type="text" id="Nick" placeholder="Nickname">
<!-- We pass the event object into our function as a parameter -->
<a id="btn" onclick="submit(event)" href="index.html">Submit</a>
```

**index.js**

```
function callNick(){
    // get the variable from the current location
    var theNick = window.location.href.split('?n=')[1];
    alert(theNick);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<button onclick="callNick()">Click Me to view your Nickname.</button>
```

[▶︎ **Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r8fvu82iup6YSY4WKpBr?p=preview) <sub>where "form" has been changed to "index" and "index" to "result".</sub>

**Note :**
To pass multiple variables, you can use the `&` delimiter, and then use the `window.location.search` property as done in [this  CSS-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/).
[▶︎ **Multiple vars plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OrD0ezCu9Czmg8a2VIl5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to store the variable in the local storage object of the window object, this way you can set its value on the first page and retrieve it on the second.

page 1

```
window.localStorage.setItem("yourVariable", "yourValue");
```

page 2

```
var myVar = localStorage.getItem("yourVariable");
```

Only one 'caveat': this is a html5 feature, so it comes with limitations, check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for more info.